# Point to an object on a container

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, containers

Is this a valid good practice? (assume that `ARENAPLAYER` is a struct)

```
ARENAPLAYER* CArena::GetPlayer( u_long idPlayer )
{
    map<u_long, ARENAPLAYER>::iterator it = m_mArenaMap.find( idPlayer );
    if( it != m_mArenaMap.end() )
        return &it->second;
    return NULL;
}
```

If it is, will the pointer point directly to the object inside the map? Any changes made by the pointer will change the object in the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pointers to the objects inside the `std::map<u_long, AREANPLAYER>` like this. The objects inside a map stay put as long as the map lives and the object isn't erased from the map.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to do this. `operator[]` returns a reference to the value stored, allowing you to change values without mucking around with pointers.